# Cauchy riemann and analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

At what points, if any, is $f(z)$ analytic?

$f(z)=(2x+y−x^2y)+i(3+2y−xy^2).$

Please help, very confused..

I know how to compare the C-R equations and know how to find them.  One set yields the unit circle.  I am supposed to answer at what points is $f(z)$ analytic, how do I state that?  Where is it analytic?  Or is it nowhere analytic?  Thanks..

Comment: One set of what? There are 2 C-R equations, and an analytic  function has to satisfy both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function to be analytic at a point, it needs to satisfy Cauchy-Riemann not only at that point but in an entire open neighborhood of the point.  So if you found that Cauchy-Riemann was satisfied only on the unit circle, $f(z)$ would be analytic nowhere, since there is no nonempty open set on which Cauchy-Riemann is satisfied.